# Delete an image only when user clicks in my "yes" link of my own dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery with some images, and I have a link in each image to delete it:

```
<div class="galery"> 
  echo '<ul>';
  while ($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<li id="'.$result['id'].'">';
    echo '<img src="'.$result['img'].'" />';
    echo '<a href="#" id="'.$resul['id'].'" class="galerydel">Delete</a>';
    echo '</li>';
      }
  echo '</ul>';
</div>
```

And then I have a jQuery script to delete my image using ajax:
I get my id of each image an then I have my ajax $.post:

```
var url = 'deleteImages.php';
$('.galery ul').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
 var delid = $(this).attr('id');
 $.post(url,{action:'del_images',image:delid},function(){

 });
 return false;
});
```

And then I have my php.file, where I get my image id `$imageId = $_POST['image'];` and action `$_POST['action'];`
 and then I do my delete in my gallery table where id is = `$imageId`.

And this is working fine, but now I want to have a dialog message asking user if he have sure that wants to remove image, 
so I have a div for a dialog like this:

```
<div class="delete_dialog">
    <div class="delete">
        <p>Do you really want to delete this image?</p>
        <a href="#">Yes</a>
        <a href="#">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I want to show this div when I click in my link to delete each image:

```
var url = 'deleteImages.php';
$('.galery ul').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
 var delid = $(this).attr('id');
 $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        ('.delete').fadeIn("slow");
 });
 $.post(url,{action:'del_images',image:delid},function(){

 });
 return false;
}); ´
```

And now, when I click in my delete link Im open my dialog, but Im also removing my news without answer to my dialog.

Do you know how can I use my dialog, if I click in yes I do my delete, but If I click in no I just close my dialog?

Im reading about this for hours, and I just saw examples using jQuery dialog, and its easy because we can use buttons (yes and no).

And I also saw examples with `if(confirm(Do you really want to delete this image?){my ajax here}` and it is also easy to do.

But Im trying to do with my own dialog, and like this I really dont know how we can do this.

Can you please give me some help??

**What Im trying:**

```
var url = 'deleteImages.php';
$('.galery ul').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
 var delid = $(this).attr('id');
 $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        ('.delete').fadeIn("slow");
 });
 $("a#delete").click(function(){
    $('.galerry ul li[id="'+ delid +'"]').css('background','red');
 $.post(url,{action:'del_images',image:delid},function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.galery ul li[id="'+ delid +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
    },500);
    $('.delete').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
    });
 });
 $("a#toggleDialog").click(function(){
   $('.delete').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Well bind the necessary event handlers to your links …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add some identificators to you "Yes/No" links (ids, attributes or something else):

   `<div class="delete_dialog">
       <div class="delete">
           <p>Do you really want to delete this image?</p>
           <a href="#" id="delete">Yes</a>
           <a href="#" id="toggleDialog">No</a>
       </div>
   </div>`
2. Add handler to links like:

   `$("a#delete").click(function(){
      //your post method
   });
   $("a#toggleDialog").click(function(){
      //hide dialog
   });`
3. Change your open dialog handler to show dialog only:

   `$('.galery ul').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
        var delid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
           ('.delete').fadeIn("slow");
        });
   });`

P.S. also you should pass the `delid` variable to "Yes" handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nicolai! Now Im just deleting my images when I click on my dialog "yes". But Im not having sucess closing my dialogs. When I click in yes and "no" links. Do you see what Im doing wrong? I udpdate my question with what Im trying.

Comment: @Marby , The problem maybe in calling 2 times the `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`. I got the following error on calling the inner `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. So try to use:  `$('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow");` and `$('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast");` [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/66zz5/)